# D3: ordinal scales, rangebands, and the new york subway

Tags: d3.js

I've got a visualization showing median income levels in census tracts that the NYC subway runs through (image here — https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17156665/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-08%20at%209.56.20%20PM.png). Looking to clearly show which stops are in which boroughs. Using this file for data (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0ApL2ZVhpOmONdFdTUWhxV252elNORVNqT0g5Y0NzV1E&output=html). Thinking the best way is to just draw a single vertical line when the county switches, and then appending the name of the borough at the bottom.

Right now I've got a series of rects in the background with an if statement coloring each, but it's pretty clunky. Have played around with ordinal scales and rangebands to no avail. Any better solutions greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be great if you could set up a jsFiddle showing what you have already achieved and then ask a specific question about some aspect you want to improve.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @ChrisJamesC. New to all of this. Just dropped the code in here — http://jsfiddle.net/tLH49/. In an ideal world I'd be able to use an ordinalscale and append "manhattan" once until the subway moves to brooklyn, then draw a vertical line, write brooklyn, until it moves into queens, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is a really interesting juxtaposition of data!)

IMO an ordinal scale is too unwieldy for this, but more importantly, there would be a problem in the case in which a line goes through the same borough more than once (like the **M** line, which starts and ends in Queens); because ordinal scale expects unique values.

Probably the best solution is to first build an array of data representing each borough's start position and the number of stops it spans. E.g. for the **M** line, it would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "county": "81",
    "countyName": "Queens"
    "start": 1,
    "span": 14
  },
  {
    "county": "61",
    "countyName": "Manhattan"
    "start": 15,
    "span": 10
  },
  {
    "county": "47",
    "countyName": "Brooklyn"
    "start": 25,
    "span": 7
  },
  {
    "county": "81",
    "countyName": "Queens"
    "start": 32,
    "span": 5
  }
]
```

One (somewhat cryptic but pretty concise) way to create this data array is calling the `reduce()` method on your filtered data. Like this:

```
    boroughs = filtered_data.reduce(
      function(memo, stop, i) {
        var len = memo.length;
        if(len == 0 || (memo[len - 1].county != stop.county)) {
          memo.push({
            county: stop.county,
            start: i+1,
            span: 1
            countyName: "foo"// This needs a dictionary mapping county code to name 
          });
        }
        else {
          memo[len - 1].span++;
        }
        return memo;
      },
      []
    )
```

After constructing this data, you'd bind it to a d3 selection and create a group for each entry. I.e, if a line goes through 3 boroughs, you'd create 3 groups. Inside each group you can append a `text` for the borough's name and a `rect` or `line` for delineation. Something like this:

```
  // note the use of your `stop_scale` for calculating positions/widths
  d3.selectAll('g.borough').data(boroughs)
    gCounties.enter()
      .append('g')// Create a group
      .attr('class', 'borough'
      .attr('transform', function(d) {// move the group to its appropriate x position
        return 'translate(' + stop_scale(d.start+1) + ')';
      })
      .each(function(d, i) {// inside each group:
        // append a rect (this is just an example)
        d3.select(this)
          .append('rect')
          .style('stroke', '#000')
          .attr('x', 0)
          .attr('width', stop_scale(d.span))
          .attr('height', 50);// This height should be changed to match your chart
        // append a text
        d3.select(this)
          .append('text')
          .text(d.countyName);
      });
```

---

As an aside, your code could use refactoring. You shouldn't have to repeat code between the `draw_first_line` and `update_chart` functions. For more info on this, check out *General Update Pattern* (parts I, II, and III) on the [d3 tutorials page](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials).

Comment: Thanks so much. Attempting to implement it now.

Comment: @larrybuch Good to hear. This is a fun visualization. Would be cool to see the working version (you could post a link here when it's ready).

Comment: Just remembering to post this @meetamit! Thanks again for the help — http://www.newyorker.com/sandbox/business/subway.html

Comment: @larrybuch Lol, I'm "in the know" enough such that I already came across it independently. Good job!